# Workbench - Picklist Value is translated but still in english language for Users

Tags: workbench, translation-workbench

I've translated the status picklist values into portuguese in the parent object, but the user still seeing the picklist option in english language in the child object. The workbench option is portuguese and the values are translated. Who knows what the reason of this issue?

Comment: I'm confused. You mention a child object. Does the child object use the same translated picklist or a picklist of it's own? If the latter, you need to translate it too! Or, are the child RECORDS from the same object which would be a different issue?

Comment: Hi crmprogdev! I've created a formula field in the Credit object that shows the status of the payment record. The status is a picklist field of the Payment object and it's translated in the workbench and I can see the translated word in the payment record, but in the credit record remain in english.

Comment: It would seem that you'll need to do a translation for the formula field on the 2nd object (Credit) in addition to the first one. Salesforce doesn't know there's a translation into portuguese for the `formula field` values since you've not created one for display on that object.

Comment: crmprogdev - it's not possible to translate the picklist values in the second object, because there's no values in the formula field to be translated. Formula Field just displays the selected status in the payment object on the credit object.

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense now that I think about it further. That would seem to be a limitation related to formula fields. I'm trying to think whether the formula field would have any means of knowing there's a translation for that value on the source object when displayed on the child object. Let me see what I can find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at [Translatable Customizations](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=translatable_customizations.htm&language=en_US), Formula Fields are not listed as something that can be customized via translation workbench. However, from looking at [Merge Fields Overview](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=valid_merge_fields.htm&language=da_2), where it says

> If you're using the Translation Workbench to translate custom field names, users can look up merge fields in their chosen language.

it would seem there may be a workaround if you do a translation of the `field name` on your `child object`. That would seem to be the only way for you to do this that I can find.